# How to return all errors descriptions with Identity in ASP.NET Core v3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am learning to do login/register with Identity in asp.net core and i am trying to add errors on register and here is my code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Username,
                    Email = model.Email,
                };

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var signInresult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, false, false);

        if (signInresult.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        List<IdentityError> errorList = result.Errors.ToList();
        string errors = "";

        foreach (var error in errorList) 
        {
            errors = errors + error.Description.ToString();
        }

        return Content(errors);
    }

    return Redirect("Index");
}
```

The problem here is the errors in errorList are returned one by one instead of all of them like, I get "username is taken" or "password must contain a letter". But not all of them at once. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem here is the errors in errorList are returned one by one instead of all of them like,

If I understand right, you don't want to use foreach to get the error one by one , you could get all errors as follows

```
else
{
    List<IdentityError> errorList = result.Errors.ToList();
    var errors = string.Join(", ", errorList.Select(e=>e.Description));

    return Content(errors);
}
```